# Series command does not work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
 Series[ Exp[Sin [Sqrt[1 + x^2]]], {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

> ```
> E^Sin[Sqrt[1 + x^2]]
> ```

Output is same as input whereas I want this answer...

> ```
> E^Sin[1/(2 x) + x + ...]
> ```

*WITHOUT* having to manually expand the square root separately. I thinking of a long expression where many Exponentials and Sines and square roots are present in that expression.

Comment: Try `D[Exp[Sin[Sqrt[1+x^2]]]]/.x->Infinity` and see the result obtained.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
MapAt[Normal[Series[#, {x, \[Infinity], 1}]] &, expr, {2, 1}]

(*  E^Sin[1/(2 x) + x]  *)
```

Have fun!